# How to send POST Request in python and get proper json response?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I want to get POST Web service data in python. For that purpose, I tried below:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','charset': 'utf-8'}
url = 'https://a.b.c.com/count/WebService.asmx/ReadJSON'
data = {'tick': '123456A123456B'}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print response.status_code
print response.text
```

**Above code output:**

```
200
{"a":""}
```

But Actually, **key "a" has some value** which I'm not getting. I don't understand it's giving me status code as 200 i.e. OK then why I'm not able to get the proper JSON response. Is I missed something in code?

Comment: use `response.json()` instead of `response.text` and you don't need to dump your dictionary to string, you can pass it as is

Comment: If I passed, response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers) I'm getting {u'StackTrace': u'', u'Message': u'There was an error processing the request.', u'ExceptionType': u''} error.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `json=data` to pass json in requests but not manually modify headers, and you should use `response.json()` to get json result if you make sure it is.

```
import requests

headers = {'charset': 'utf-8'}
url = 'https://a.b.c.com/count/WebService.asmx/ReadJSON'
data = {'tick': '123456A123456B'}
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
print response.status_code
print response.json()
```

Comment: @Sraw- Please see above comment. I tried your solution it's not working for me. I'm getting same output as shown in answer.

Comment: @kit Are you sure you are using `json=data` but not `data=data`?

Comment: @Sraw- Yes. I'm using json=data only. I changed it from data=data to json=data.

Comment: @kit you could print out `response.request.headers` to compare two different implementations. Further, if it really doesn't work for you because of some strange reasons, you can just change to use `response.json()` to get json result.

Comment: @Sraw- I'm getting response.request.header as {'Content-Length': '47', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} and I used respose.json() only to see the data.

Comment: @kit As you can see, using `json=data` automatically add `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` into headers for you, so I don't know why you still have an error if you implement a standard server. More, what do you mean "only to see the data"? If you cannot get what you expect by `response.json()`, check your server first, does it really return what you expect?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did u get the chance to resolve it?